# Как убрать водяной знак на видео ТикТок с помощью python? Можете подробнее объяснить как оно работает?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Мне вдруг стало интересно как работает бот в телегея, который может убирать водяной знак на видео. Кто-то может объяснить как он это делает?

Comment: Наверняка нейросетями. Думаю, примерно так: обнаружить, где находится этот знак, пометить эти пикселы каким-то образом, попытаться с помощью нейросети угадать, какие пикселы должны быть в этих местах, опираясь на остальную картинку.

Comment: Вообще в идеале показать пример